# Don't write innerHTML in same span everytime function is called

Tags: javascript

```
    var villains = 500;
var hero = 500;
function beth() {

    he();

    }


function betv() {
    

}
function he() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
    var vhp = villains - x;
    villains=vhp;
    if (villains< 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = "Heroes have won";
        
        document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "<br/>Villains have lost to heroes";
        
    } else {

        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML += "<br/>Heroes have dealt "  + x
                +  " damage on villains.<br/>Villains have "  + vhp
                + " hp left.";

        
                
        
        vok();
    }
    },3000);
}
function vok() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
    var hhp = hero - y;
    hero=hhp;
    if (hero<0) {
        document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "<br/>Heroes have " + 0 +" Hp left";
        
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = "<br/>Heroes have lost to villains";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML += "<br/>Villains have dealt "
                + y + " damage on Heroes.<br/>Heroes have "  + hhp
                + " hp left.";

        
                
        
he();
    }
    },3000);
}
```

**Abve Code is for js its printing text1 newtext2 newtext3 while I want text1 text2 newtext1 newtext2 newnewtext1 newnewtext2. Any tips or suggestions how can we do it? Would appreciate any answers or feedbacks**. I also want after the finish the condition for if is met to reset everything

Comment: You're explicitly setting `innerHTML = ...`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents#creating_and_placing_new_nodes

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the `span` every time by assigning new value to it (=). Instead you should append the value using `+=`, wherever you want your span value to be added.

```
document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML += "Heroes have dealt " + x + " damage on villains.";
```

Comment: Yeah thanks it helped its just the span text are going out of div border I set haha

Comment: Add line break `<br>`. I missed it.

Comment: It's solved but I want text like span1, span its just writing span1 span1 span1,, span2 span2 span 2 while I want span1 span 2,,newspan1 newspan2

Comment: Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can. Wrap the `span1` , `span2` in a `div`/`p`. Then append the whole of `span1+ span2` to the div/p, instead of  appending to `span1` & `span2` separately

Comment: How do I do so?

Comment: `document.getElementById("result-div").innerHTML += span1text + span2text` instead of `document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML += span1text; document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML += span2text;`

Comment: Can you add runnable code snippet with minimum reproducible example with your HTML code too.

Comment: Sure I will add a runnable code

Comment: You can run the code here https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/DMdKY4NFxhJPzI9N the delay is 3 sec so you can watch what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are using the `=` operator, which means to replace/overwrite the value currently set to the HTML element (in this case, the `span` element).

To fix this issue, you need to replace `=` with `+=`. The `+=` operator appends to the *end* of the string, instead of overwriting the text.

So, you would change your code to be the following. The code below updates the `span` tag to have some extra text at the end, instead of overwriting it all.

```js
const welcome = document.querySelector("#welcome");
welcome.innerHTML += "I'm on Stack Overflow!";
```

```html
<!-- Extra whitespace is intentional -->
<span id="welcome">Hello! </span>
```

However, if you want to add some text to the *beginning* of the text, you can just use the code below.

```js
const intro = document.querySelector("#intro");

// The whitespace is intentional
intro.innerHTML = "Welcome to Stack Overflow! " + intro.innerHTML
```

```html
<span id="intro">First check the Help page.</span>
```

---

In conclusion, there are two ways to add to HTML.

- Use the `+=` operator.
- Use the `+` operator (with extra code).

Comment: += works but I need span text to be like span1 span2 span1 span2 but += is writing span1 span1 span1, span2 snap2 snap2

Comment: Have you tried the `+` operator (as shown in the other answer)?

Comment: Yes using + signs added the span texts in new row without overwriting the old spans but i need to write text newtext1, text2 newtext2 while += is writing text1 newtext1 newtextq, text2 newtext2 newtext2